# Initialise a new dataframe from another dataframe sub-slice along with its column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
 X = dataset.iloc[:, 2:-1].values
 df_X = pd.DataFrame(X)
 df_X.head()
```

I am slicing my columns to the index specified in the array. Is there any way I can show the columns names after slicing rather than showing the index? I am new to pandas.

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uE55h.png)

Comment: Thanks for accepting :) Side note, you can also upvote answers if they were useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When initialising a DataFrame, specify a `columns` parameter. You'll need to slice those headers out from `dataset` the same way you slice out `X`.

```
X = dataset.iloc[:, 2:-1].values
c = df.columns[2:-1]

df_X = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=c)
```

Answer (score 0):

1st. Save the columns before the split:

```
columns = dataset.columns
```

2nd. Split the columns as you did before.

3rd. On the splitted df do:

```
splitted_df.columns = columns
```